Not getting to next line, Java
This has been solved; my professor just sent a mass email that there is an issue with the format we are using. Thank you all for you help. Until its fixed its unclear what my real problem will be if at all.
The issue I'm having is that it refuses to move to the next line. For item 1 and 2 ive tried next as well as next line. I get the same error either way. The program is expected to take a product name which can be one or two words. The format being used is kinda the required format the professor wanted. He mentioned that next line HAS to be used for the second item input.
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class ShoppingCartPrinter {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
          int i = 0;
          String productName = "";
          int productPrice = 0;
          int productQuantity = 0;
          int cartTotal = 0;
      
          ItemToPurchase item1 = new ItemToPurchase();
          ItemToPurchase item2 = new ItemToPurchase();
    
          //get item 1 details
          System.out.println("Item 1");
          System.out.println("Enter the item name: "); 
          item1.setItemName(scnr.nextLine()); //get and set item 1 name
    
          System.out.println("Enter the item price: ");
          item1.setItemPrice(scnr.nextInt()); //get and set item 1 price
    
          System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");
          item1.setItemQuantity(scnr.nextInt()); //get and set item 1 quantity
          
          scnr.nextLine(); //consume next line (i've tried with and without this part as well)
          
          System.out.println("Item 2");
          System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
          item2.setItemName(scnr.nextLine()); //get and set item 2 name
          
          System.out.println("Enter the item price: ");
          item2.setItemPrice(scnr.nextInt()); //get and set item 2 price
          
          System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");
          item2.setItemQuantity(scnr.nextInt()); //get and set item 2 quantity
          
          System.out.println();
          
          System.out.println("TOTAL COST");

          System.out.println(item1.getItemName() + " @ $" + item1.getItemPrice() + " = " 
             + (item1.getItemPrice() * item1.getItemQuantity())); 

          System.out.print("Total: " + (item1.getItemPrice() + item2.getItemPrice()));
          // Add costs of two items and print total
          // cartTotal = item one price + item two price
          // Totoal Cost
          // item one information
          // item two information
          // Total output
          
          return;
       }
    }

Error being returned:
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        at ShoppingCartPrinter.main(ShoppingCartPrinter.java:21)

Input:
canned pears 5 1
fresh apples 2 1

**this is how input has to go into the zY Books IDE, im not sure why :(
Item 1
Enter the item name: canned pears 
Enter the item price: 5 //this is where the output terminates


Why are "canned pears 5 1" all on the same line? Are you using one of those programming websites that has a fixed input format that you can't change?

@user85421 It's not. The issue is that the inputs are all on the same line and nextLine reads everything.

The formatting when posting the input was off, they are being entered on separate lines; Im having to use zY Books lab IDE.

I updated it to reflect the proper input, im sorry about that

@AshleyBrown I mean your code expects that "canned pears" is on its own line, but your input also has "5 1" in that line.

@Sweeper I see what you mean now, for whatever diabolical reason it expects it this way

Can you combine the output and input step by step? example: Enter name : "apple", Enter price: 2

This question is similar to: Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

what do you mean by this is where the output terminates? if it terminates there, how did you get the rest of them?

If you entire the input as follows:
canned pears 5 1
fresh apples 2 1

then the entire first line (canned pears 5 1) will be consumed by scnr.nextLine().
Scanner will then attempt to read the next token using scnr.nextInt() which will throw the exception. The reason for this is that the next token at this point is not 5 as that has already been consumer by scnr.nextLine(), so now the next token is fresh on the next line (fresh apples 2 1) which is not an int.
If you enter each part of the input separately (name, price, quantity) each will be read by the scanner separately (canned pears as a line into a Sting, 5 as an int, 1 as an int.) which works as each part of the input matches the type of token the scanner is looking for.
To see what happens, run your code through a debugger to observe the values.  It might help to extract the result of what is read by the scanner into a variable to make it easier to see the value.
For example:
String line = scnr.nextLine()
item1.setItemName();


readLine consumes the whole line, so when you do item1.setItemName(scnr.nextLine());, the price and quantity ("5" and "1") are also read and set as the name of the item. Then, you call nextInt, and ends up not finding any numbers to read, as the next thing to be read is the word "fresh" on the next line.

Since you mentioned that the item name is either 1 or 2 words, you can do:
String name = scnr.next();
if (!scnr.hasNextInt()) {
    name += " " + scnr.next();
}
item1.setItemName(name);

// do the same for item2 - you can reuse the 'name' variable :)

next reads until the next delimiter, which by default is any whitespace character. So roughly speaking, next() reads the next "word". We then check if the next thing to read is an integer, using hasNextInt. If it is not an integer, read another word. If it is, we assume that the number is the price for the item, and stops reading the name.
Note that this will not preserve the whitespace between the two words in an item name. If the item name is fresh    apples (with multiple spaces), the item name will be set to fresh apple, with only one space. This also assumes that numbers are never a part of the item name. e.g. "iPhone 15" will never be an item name.
To "properly" do this, so that whitespace in the item name is preserved, and numbers can occur in item names, I'd use findInLine with a regular expression (though this might be beyond what you are expected to do):
scnr.findInLine("(.+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)");
MatchResult match = scnr.match();
item1.setItemName(match.group(1));
item1.setItemPrice(Integer.parseInt(match.group(2)));
item1.setItemQuantity(Integer.parseInt(match.group(3)));
scnr.nextLine(); // consume the new line character
// do the same for item2...

